# How get top post view for today for today post

Tags: posts, views

I insert today 20 post for example.

And i need to get top post that show today from today post.

I try this code but its show me top post view for all time. But I need only for today post.

```
$day = date('d');
$month = date('m');
$year = date('Y'); 
query_posts(
    array(  'post_type' => 'post',
            'order'     => 'ASC',
            'meta_key' => 'post_views_count',
            'orderby'   => 'meta_value', 
            'year' => '$year',
            'monthnum' => '$month',
            'day' => '$day',
    )
);
```

Comment: You should never use `query_posts()`, it will do funky things to your blog.  Instead look into the `pre_get_posts` action hook, the `get_posts()` function or the `WP_Query` class.

Comment: ^^ That said, can I assume that the vale of the `post_views_count` meta key is updated every time a post is viewed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your question does not state, I'm assuming that this is not your main query, but rather a stand alone that tells the visitor the most viewed page of the day.

Therefore I believe that an instance of the [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) class is what you need.

```
/** Query the posts to find the one with the most views from today */
$today = getdate();
$args = array(
    'meta_key'          => 'post_views_count',
    'orderby'           => 'meta_value_num',
    'posts_per_page'    => 1,
    'post_type'         => 'post',
    'post_status'       => 'publish',
    'date_query'        => array(
        array(
            'year'  => $today['year'],
            'month' => $today['mon'],
            'day'   => $today['mday']
        )
    )
);
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
echo '<pre>$my_query: '; print_r($my_query); echo '</pre>';

/** Check for results and output them */
if($my_query->have_posts()) : while($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();

        /** Your code goes here, inside The Loop */
        echo '<pre>' . get_the_title() . ' (' . get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'post_views_count', true) . ')' . '</pre>';

    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
endif;
```

Comment: hello ,, I try your code but its not return me any post,

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that you have posts with today's date?